# how to disable automatic symbol highlighting VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode when the cursor is on a symbol (function name, var name, etc) the symbol gets highlighted automatically across the document.

Here is an example:

[image: screenshot]

I've searched multiple times in the settings file but the only match for `highlight` is `editor.selectionHighlight` which I have set to `false` and it does something else anyway.

How can I disable this automatic highlighting?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: No I didn't. You can complain here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5351

Comment: @FélixSanz check the answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This feature was just implemented.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5351#event-982256414

The solution will be (once the changes are pushed to the public channel in March 2017) to use `editor.occurrencesHighlight` in the config file.